# how to add div after each multiple of 5 using jquery in ul

Tags: jquery

How can i achieve the following  using jquery. I tried to use css but to no avail so i am thinking of using jquery.How can i achieve this?? I tried to append but to no avail.

```
 <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: where is your code of what you tried?

Comment: please check 'undefineds' answer and do not put divs in a ul; it makes your markup invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [nth child selector.](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('ul li:nth-child(5n)').after('<li class="clear"></li>');
```

Comment: another poster who said you should not put div's in a UL is totally right. I updated my answer for the sake of cleanliness, but the actually jquery does not change. The answer is the same.

Comment: This would be my preferred method - the easiest to understand and the most concise (IMO)

Answer (score -2):

try the following... It should work..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(i,val){
    i++;
    if(i%5==0){
    $(this).append('<div class="clear"></div>');
    }
    });
    });
```